# Получил данные после оптимизации, как вывести на график в R

Tags: графика, r

Оптимизация портфеля акций, получил данные после оптимизации, как вывести на график полученный результат, для наглядного сравнения линий доходности в R?
Должно быть две линии(суммы), одна показывает когда веса в портфеле равны(пунктирная линия), а(красная линия) показывает когда веса разные.График который снизу он показывает насколько накопленная сумма отклонялась от предыдущего максимума.
Данные `"data_a.txt"` на диске вот ссылка:https://yadi.sk/d/lM5ZFx2QM8cGzw

```
#Загрузка необходимых пакетов
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
library(zoo)
library(quadprog)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.quadprog)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(xts)

#чтение текстовых данных из файла
result <- read.table(file = "data_a.txt")

#преобразовываем дату
result$V1<-strptime(as.character(result$V1),"%d.%m.%Y ")

#переводим в (timeSeries)  первый столбец с датой отбрасываем, он встает на место индекса 
result <- xts(result[,-1] , result$V1)

#Формирование портфеля
init<-portfolio.spec(assets=colnames(result))

#Условие: сумма весов порфеля равна 1
init<-add.constraint(portfolio = init,type="full_investment")

#Условие: минимальный вес = 0.05, максимальный = 0.5
init<-add.constraint(portfolio = init,type="box",min=0.05,max=0.5)

#Портфель с максимизацией дохода
maxret<-add.objective(portfolio = init,type='return',name='mean')
opt_maxret<-optimize.portfolio(R=result, portfolio=maxret, optimize_method = "ROI",trace=TRUE)


#Портфель с минимизацией просадок по ETL
etl<-add.objective(portfolio = init, type="risk", name="ETL")
opt_etl<-optimize.portfolio(R=result, portfolio=etl,    optimize_method = "ROI", trace=TRUE)

#Портфель с максимизацией дохода при заданном уровне просадки
mean_etl<-add.objective(portfolio=init, type="return",name="mean")
mean_etl<-add.objective(portfolio=mean_etl, type="risk", name="var",arguments=list(p=0.95))
opt_mean_etl<-optimize.portfolio(R=result, portfolio=mean_etl, optimize_method = "DEoptim", traceDE=5, arguments=list(NP = 200, itermax = 300,  F = 0.2, CR = 0.8))
```

Желаемый результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы бы написали, что именно у вас не получается. а то вопрос в духе «нарисуйте мне график с пунктиром и линиями, вот по этим данным, и, главное, расскажите как вы это сделали» — совсем не подходит для данного сайта. см. [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: взял данные четырех акций за 4 года, если суммировать, то получим красную линию(сумму 4 акций), таким образом веса распределились по 25% на акцию, для примера, допустим если их было бы 5 шт. то по 20% вообщем равные доли весов для получения суммы. Применив пакеты библиотек(PortfolioAnalytics),(ROI),(ROI.plugin.quadprog),(ROI.plugin.glpk) можно оптимизировать веса таким образом что бы получить желаемый результат, в данном примере было выбрано три желаемых результат первый(максимизациея дохода), второй(минимизациея просадок), третий(максимизацией дохода при заданном уровне просадки). Вопрос:

Comment: Вопрос: как из полученных данных(веса акций распределились по разному же исходя из примененных условий) построить линию сумму исходя из полученных весов на акцию. В примере три условия, получиться три разные суммы(линии)?